# flutter count the time remain for given hour updated by seconds

Tags: flutter

I want to add this feature to my app in a container so, I have the time in h:m:s for example if the given time was (6:27pm) I want this result (time remaining 02:21:02)

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want is just:

```
target.difference(DateTime.now()).toString().split('.')[0])
```

I did `.split('.')[0]` the Duration to remove the fractions of second.

[image]

### Full source code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CountDown(
          target: DateTime.now().add(
            Duration(minutes: 5),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CountDown extends StatelessWidget {
  final DateTime target;

  const CountDown({
    Key key,
    this.target,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1)),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            Text('Time until ${DateFormat.Hms().format(target)}'),
            const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
            Text(target.difference(DateTime.now()).toString().split('.')[0]),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```